# Is it possible to use EGit without having to Share Project?

Tags: egit

For now, I only have a local `.git` subdirectory under my Eclipse workspace and I don't feel the need to `push` it to shared repository.

I would like to also use EGit, but its [user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Create_Repository) provides only a `Share Project` way to do that.

Can I re-use my local `.git` without having to push/publish/share it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Share project" in this context doesn't mean, that you have to share your project to a remote repository. It only means, that this Eclipse project is connected to a (local) Git repository. And yes, in this case you have to share your project, so that Eclipse detects the Git repository.

I think, "Share project" originates from a time, where there were only centralized VCS, and in that case, your project really was shared with a central server. Now with decentralized VCS, another term may be better suited.